# How to prevent some users from upgrading application from Android market?

Tags: android, google-play

We have an application, that can itself be downloaded for free, but works with paid, licensed data. Some users buy particular version of the data while others buy right to use latest data for some period of time. Now as the application evolves, it eventually stops supporting data older than some date. So obviously users who have those data licensed, but no license for newer data don't want to upgrade. But if we publish new version on the market, they would see it and if they upgrade, they will have trouble downgrading back to version that actually works for them.

So can we somehow instruct the market application not to offer upgrades for particular user or some hack to achieve that end?

We currently use mechanism completely independent on the market to sell and check licenses for the data, but could consider different mechanism (like the android in-app billing support or something) if it could help solving the problem.

Comment: Keyword: **backward compatibility**. This is the best solution you can think of, it's clever, reliable and doesn't need a cumbersome layer on top of what you do have already.

Comment: So, what did you implement, Jan? You have some solid suggestions below, but did not upvote or accept any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an option that market will contain an installer that will download and install another `.apk` containing the core of the application locally.

We already have an installer dialog in the application for downloading the data and user has to enter it when using the application for the first time, so it can be made responsible for the application core too.

Comment: You mentioned that downloading the data prompts for installation; is that a Market APK being downloaded? If so, and the app core APKs are not in the Market and downloaded from a 3rd party source, some phones would be prevented from installing these APKs (due to some phones having 3rd party app installs disabled).

Comment: @Rajiv M: We tried it with that option turned off and all that happened was that it asked user to confirm installation as it would anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have two options to "disable" upgrades:

- Use a different signing key - this will prevent installation without removal of the previous app, but upgrade notifications will still appear (I think)
- Use a different package name - this will prevent upgrades since it is a completely separate app so far as the market is concerned, and also has the side-effect that old versions are still available for those users who are licensed for that data version.

The second option may be a better match since you can roll out upgrades if necessary for bug-fixes, but can also ensure that wholly new versions are not detected as an upgrade.

---

EDIT:

Totally agree that the above options are cumbersome and don't really solve the issue as-is.

As you mentioned however, you could use [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-purchase-type), but given the nature of your requirements, you'd have to use unmanaged purchases which means you'll need some infrastructure to manage authorising purchases and preventing people from buying the same license too many times.

I'm guessing you've already got much of that infrastructure in place to handle distribution of the data though.

Comment: Of course that's the workarounds. It has two disadvantages: some users should be getting updates in our case, only some shouldn't. Plus if it will be different application, it will not accumulate popularity on the market.

Comment: Ad edit: We indeed already have infrastructure for selling the content. The application was already distributed on Windows Mobile and preinstalled on single-purpose devices and such, so we needed it already. That's not our problem. Our problem is how to handle upgrades in android market.

Answer (score 1):

Can the data not contain a "format version" number at the start of the file?

Then you can program the app to read version 1 files, a new app needs more fields on the data source, so you create version 2 data, which adds extra fields, version 1 app see's the data needs a newer app, so tells the user to upgrade.

Version 2 app should know how to read version 1 files and version 2 files (perhaps create a reader Interface and implement loaders for the different versions of files.)

You'll have to handle the missing data in v1 / old files in the loader in the v2 app. The loading of older files is the nicest way for the customer as the app shouldn't just stop working after an upgrade.

If you keep a copy of each format's data you can quickly run tests to check the new version's loader can load each file correctly, plus if the app has a bug in there you won't have to fix several app versions, just the current one.

Comment: We do have version in the data. We can certainly implement backward compatibility. The problem is that the application is unholy mess and assumes things about the data all over the place, so backward compatibility is a *lot* of work.

Comment: How about a data upgrade feature.

Comment: @baash05: Data upgrade feature is impossible, because the data is read only and would take many hours to convert. Plus data conversion implies being able to read the old data anyway, so it's even more work than reading the old data. We'll have to refactor this crap to allow backward compatibility anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec How about offloading.. Write a desk app that does the upgrade for your clients.  Have a link on your website to an exe, and get the user to connect their android.. pull the file off, and put a newly formatted version down.. (I'm grasping at straws.. I feel your pain)

Comment: Oh.. you could eventually expand your desk app and monitize it.. For "premium" clients.

Comment: @baash05: We have one. But nobody's going to use that for app they downloaded from Play.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I saw one of the posters suggest you have a way to read the old data.
First that's likely the best option but as you say your apps a mess. 
You should invest some time in migrating your data reading/writing to an abstraction layer. The pain your having on a (likely less than 4 year old project) is only going to get worse.

Okay.. so here's how I've dealt with it in long lived apps..

Create a migration path.. Create a new class call Migrate. 
In it have several functions to convert the version of the file from n to n-1
convert_1_to_2(fileName){check the version and upgrade data.)
convert_2_to_3(fileName)...

I suspect you have your old code, and you could write a method to convert one bit of data to the next.. 
When you add new features to the data, then you create a new convert.. No knowledge of the earlier ones would be needed, and everything would be nice and self contained. 
You could even have sub migrations, so part way along the dev cycle, you could have convert_3a_to_3b.

Now... you could archive the original version of the data in case the user wants to go back.

Comment: That's a good way to handle format changes in general. In our case it's not applicable though, because the application does not contain code to write the data at all, only to read it. And due to the LZMA2 compression, writing the data in newer format would take many hours (the compression is efficient and fast to decompress, but very slow to compress).

Comment: On a side note: Yes, the code is some 3 years old. It's initial designer managed to persuade owner to do the [worst strategic mistake](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html) and started the code from scratch, with less modular design than the earlier version. He didn't really grok modularity and object oriented programming and rewrote things from standard library and generally produced horrible code. We have to clear that mess eventually, but we also have to get it to market.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is accessed remotely, you could have the app include the version, or some hash of itself, when requesting it. And then filter the data provided based upon that information.

If you already have in-app purchasing and the infrastructure to support it, just poll for new data when the app is upgraded. If the user has purchased the license for current data, provide it. Otherwise just continue using the existing data.

Comment: The data is accessed locally. There is an installer that can fetch new version, but the problem is they are on order of gigabytes, so the user may not have time and/or sufficient connectivity to download them at some random time.

Comment: The user will need to download the data through the app, or download an enormous app from the store. Either way, the data needs to be transmitted to them. If the data needs to be downloaded anyway, could my approach work?

Comment: Your approach *does* work. User downloads the data in the application and it does tell the server which version it is and server gives it correct data. The problem however happens when the user wants to upgrade the application because market told him there is new version and we need to warn him that if he does, he'll need to update the data too or even that version of that data is not (possibly yet) available for the new version of the application.

Comment: Can they upgrade the application and still be able to use the data they have already downloaded (purchased)?

Comment: No (technically; legally they are supposed to be). If they could, there would have been absolutely no problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I'm missing something. Why can't the new application read the old data set? Did it change format?

Comment: Yes, it does. The data is huge and needs to be read fast, so there is little room for any redundancy. It's therefore not always possible to extend it in a compatible way.

Comment: To which I should add that the problem is that we can of course tell the old format from the new one, but because the application core is badly designed, it's not easy to implement separate readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not definitely prevent users to download the new version of a app they already have. You can either register a new app or check the version and user data programatically.